# Medalhas servem como "critério de desempate" no rank geral?

Tags: suporte

Eu estava dando uma olhada no [Rank Geral](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=all) de usuários e percebi que eu e o @GuilhermeNascimento estamos com a mesma pontuação, mesmo número de medalhas de prata e mesmo número de medalhas de ouro.

Porém eu estou na frente dele.

Isso se deve ao fato de eu ter medalhas de bronze a mais? Como é medido isso?

[image: Você é para mim como um Rubéns Barrichelo]

Comment: Ou será que é por causa da tag [tag:python] que está dando mais peso?

Comment: Só para afirmar, apesar do sistema arredondar o score, ainda sim houve um momento do dia que estivemos em empate, ainda sim o Wallace ficou a frente, notem que o meu userid é 3635 e o do Wallace é 4995, se fosse ordem de antiguidade, eu estaria na frente. Acho que deve ser alguma variação do sistema e até mesmo algo que não pensamos, não acredito que sejam as medalhas, mas também não desacredito.

Answer (score 7):

O motivo é o **cache** (não estou falando de cache HTTP, mas sim do "ecossistema" dos sites da SO, detalhes http://docplayer.com.br/3642486-A-arquitetura-do-stack-overflow.html)

Eu entendi o que houve, fiz um teste hoje com os usuários:

- [@gmsantos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/4751/gmsantos) (cadastrado em 2014-02-06 09:35:13Z)
- [@renan](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/4808/renan) (cadastrado em 2014-02-06 23:15:11Z)

Vejam eu votei no @renan para que ambos ficassem com 10.478, o @renan estava uma posição abaixo do @gmsantos então votei para igualar os pontos e ficou assim:

[image: 1]

Todavia depois de alguns minutos (ou hora) voltei a olhar:

[image: 2]

Vejam que a posição mudou, então o que o @bigown disse está correto, o que determina a posição são os pontos e se o usuário é mais novo, no caso o @renan é mais novo por algumas horas então ele ficará na frente e as medalhas não impactam no posicionamento.

Então se o @WallaceMaxters empatar comigo eu ainda irei aparecer na frente durante alguns minutos, mas assim que o *cache* for atualizado ele irá aparecer na frente, já que ele se cadastrou 12 dias depois de mim.

Comment: Ou seja, mais pontos em menos tempo ganham, tem lógica.

Answer (score 4):

No momento que eu olhei não estavam empatados (31.192 x 31.155) e um empate seria bem transitório, e irrelevante. Até onde eu sei o desempate ocorre pela antiguidade do usuário.

Comment: Eu esqueci que rolava um "arredondamento para cima"

Comment: Essa informação também não procede.

Comment: Mas está na foto! Se é 31.2K, está arredondando de 31.192... Foi isso que quis dizer.

Comment: Eu só posso falar do que você disse, sobre o que você quis dizer só você pode falar :) Há apenas arredondamento.

Comment: Não é pela antiguidade, eu me cadastrei cerca de 10 dias (*2014-01-30 16:35:34Z*) antes e o @WallaceMaxters se cadastrou em *2014-02-11 00:53:32Z*, também não acho que sejam as medalhas, mas ainda sim é uma possibilidade.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento você tem alguma referência sobre isso, ou algum motivo que te leva acreditar nisso? Pelo que eu já vi acontecendo é pela antiguidade.

Comment: @bigown não tenho referencia, eu notei isto hoje cedo, entre as 9:00am e  13:00, não me lembro ao certo. Se ocorrer novamente eu verifico para confirmar. Note que eu sempre verifico os atributos `title="..."` e nunca me baseio pelas "abreviações" ou "arredondamentos", isto vale pras datas também.

Comment: Se você arrumar 2 pontos, ou perder 3, a gente vê já :D

Comment: @bigown meu limite diário já passou. Amanhã (1 hora e 9 minutos) veremos, preciso de 7 pontos.

Comment: voces devem conseguir ver qual é o criterio no monte de utilizadores com 1 de reputacao, que nao participam no site. Parece ser por antiguidade (descendente, os mais novos primeiro) como o bignown mencionou.

Comment: @BrunoCosta é a observação que eu tive.

Comment: @BrunoCosta mas também podem ser as medalhas antes da antiguidade.

Comment: @JorgeB. não pode, basta observar os padrões. Elas não tem ordem alguma. a ordem é o número do ID. Seria até um critério complicado de usar, a SE é pragmática nisso.

Comment: @JorgeB. Nao pode, como eu referi, ve nos utilizadores com 1 de reputacao. É prova que as medalhas nao é criterio de desempate