# O que significa o tempo em "visto" no perfil do usuário?

Tags: suporte, perfil, usuarios

Por exemplo, o que significa esse tempo "Visto 1 hora trás" na imagem tirada de um perfil de usuário?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Sempre achei que era porque o usuário saiu do site no tempo indicado, mas nunca tive essa certeza. O que significa de fato?

Comment: Indaguei um diamante do SOen e ele disse que "na verdade ninguém sabe ao certo o que significa, e que é apenas algo estimado", e me mandou este link: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70232/timestamp-on-question-is-later-than-profiles-seen-must-be-some-time-traveller

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Efetuei testes para checar em que momento o tempo em questão é calculado.

No primeiro, verifiquei que, mesmo estando ativo no site, seja navegando, postando comentários, analisando sinalizações e votando, o tempo só é alterado após cerca de **15 minutos**. Ou seja, mesmo que esteja ativo no site, o tempo nunca será atualizado antes de 15 minutos, conforme ilustra a imagem abaixo, sendo capturados *prints* nos intervalos mostrados na imagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No segundo teste, para comprovar o primeiro, após ter iniciado a contagem de tempo conforme imagem acima, fiquei inerte no site (sem navegar) além dos 15 minutos, conforme imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Após os 16 minutos, fiz uma navegação para ver o resultado. Como imaginei, o tempo *zerou*:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Conclusão:**

Independente de navegação ou atividade no site, o tempo só será atualizado com um intervalo mínimo de 15 minutos.

Comment: Só pra constar, para quem ainda não sabe, os sites da rede Stack Exchange usam cache em quase tudo, então os 15 minutos que citou provavelmente se trate disto. Exemplo de situação https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5467/3635 - (a arquitetura do Stack Overflow: http://docplayer.com.br/3642486-A-arquitetura-do-stack-overflow.html)

Comment: Humm.. interessante. vou dar uma olhada

Answer (score 10):

Há quanto tempo ele estava no site pela última vez. Neste caso há uma hora atrás o usuário estava usando o site. Precisa passar o *mouse*  em cima para ver os minutos e segundos.

Até onde eu sei isto não é lá muito preciso e não sei os critérios que fazem considerar que o usuário estava no site. Pode ser que basta entrar em uma página qualquer já *resete* o contador, ou pode ser que exija alguma navegação.

É uma forma de saber se usuário teve a chance de ver algo que foi postado para ele, se ele "abandonou" o site, coisas assim.

Comment: É pq abre algumas possibilidades: fez logout (acho menos provável, a não ser que esteja em uma máquina compartilhada), inatividade com o site aberto ou fechou o navegador ou a aba do site.

Comment: Ao passar o mouse só mostra o horário padrão do site de 1 hora antes. Não diz muita coisa.